# Java (Netty) SSL Server/Client with self-signed certificates throws fatal error: 80: pr0blem unwrapping net record

Tags: java, ssl, netty, self-signed

I seem not to be able to grasp they way SSL is working... or ar least I'm not able to interpret the ssl debugging output of java, so here's what I (plan to) do:
Client and Server generate their own keypair and self-signed certificate. (I only need to ensure the identity upon reconnection.) For testing I use the same key- and truststure (with only one key and certificate) on both, the server and the client. Something goes wrong during the handshake but I don't understand the error message. Read about 20 forums and so posts about this but could not figure it out so far. So can anybody tell me what this message at the bottom exactly means, please? If you need more details, please let me know. Thanks!

**Server SSL debug**

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
EndpointIdentificationAlgorithm: null
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 00 95                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 149
0000: 01 00 00 91 03 01 51 0F   F6 C7 F3 99 F4 4B 77 A8  ......Q......Kw.
0010: 43 BB A0 89 E0 D9 20 4D   9F 5A C2 E2 0E 80 87 9F  C..... M.Z......
0020: 59 9A 13 71 F7 4F 00 00   2A 00 33 C0 04 00 16 00  Y..q.O..*.3.....
0030: 05 C0 03 C0 11 C0 02 C0   07 C0 13 C0 08 C0 0C 00  ................
0040: FF C0 0D C0 0E C0 09 00   2F C0 12 00 04 00 32 00  ......../.....2.
0050: 13 00 0A 01 00 00 3E 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......>...4.2...
0060: 01 00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................
0070: 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
0080: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00  ................
0090: 0B 00 02 01 00                                     .....
New I/O worker #1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1359934919 bytes = { 243, 153, 244, 75, 119, 168, 67, 187, 160, 137, 224, 217, 32, 77, 159, 90, 194, 226, 14, 128, 135, 159, 89, 154, 19, 113, 247, 79 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 149
0000: 01 00 00 91 03 01 51 0F   F6 C7 F3 99 F4 4B 77 A8  ......Q......Kw.
0010: 43 BB A0 89 E0 D9 20 4D   9F 5A C2 E2 0E 80 87 9F  C..... M.Z......
0020: 59 9A 13 71 F7 4F 00 00   2A 00 33 C0 04 00 16 00  Y..q.O..*.3.....
0030: 05 C0 03 C0 11 C0 02 C0   07 C0 13 C0 08 C0 0C 00  ................
0040: FF C0 0D C0 0E C0 09 00   2F C0 12 00 04 00 32 00  ......../.....2.
0050: 13 00 0A 01 00 00 3E 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......>...4.2...
0060: 01 00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................
0070: 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
0080: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00  ................
0090: 0B 00 02 01 00                                     .....
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
keymanager chooseEngineServerAlias
keymanager getPrivateKey: 3eb9936d-2240-4687-bf4e-6518460e3e40
keymanager getCertificateChain: 3eb9936d-2240-4687-bf4e-6518460e3e40
%% Negotiating:  [Session-1, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1359934920 bytes = { 242, 252, 196, 36, 227, 154, 97, 148, 214, 170, 109, 188, 122, 223, 161, 62, 131, 201, 214, 11, 223, 36, 74, 224, 72, 78, 94, 50 }
Session ID:  {81, 15, 246, 200, 127, 240, 115, 234, 52, 13, 73, 40, 137, 163, 243, 8, 51, 244, 147, 87, 128, 39, 210, 175, 163, 244, 86, 238, 138, 87, 29, 43}
Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=3eb9936d-2240-4687-bf4e-6518460e3e40
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 130292698947319747550411805428932496764788133931614615268432511412918979081774531703795353050388491281785406619160787220723201364083891450242081089010992812611565317265297099663990262828027908909326882453616292013722474448961222856631109497585792129874215397389474004374746492345728806709616072944360825031857
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sun Feb 03 03:52:37 CET 2013,
               To: Wed Feb 01 03:52:37 CET 2023]
  Issuer: CN=3eb9936d-2240-4687-bf4e-6518460e3e40
  SerialNumber: [    1bd22c7d 61d1a1eb]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 94 5E 4F 74 28 A7 6C 94   25 60 4B 38 9F 7F 2D DE  .^Ot(.l.%`K8..-.
0010: 6D 3E E5 1F 55 E4 F2 14   3F 80 FF D4 24 55 B9 60  m>..U...?...$U.`
0020: 4C C3 B6 BB 68 CD 12 AD   FA BA 6D B0 76 5F 91 96  L...h.....m.v_..
0030: 08 97 9D 53 E8 28 5C DE   69 DD 30 92 F1 FE 59 21  ...S.(\.i.0...Y!
0040: 81 05 E6 E6 8D 89 6E 77   A4 6A EC 13 E5 0B D9 17  ......nw.j......
0050: 03 51 85 FB 14 D8 FA 6A   A3 52 71 57 F2 A5 CC 80  .Q.....j.RqW....
0060: 31 6D EA 64 81 4F C9 53   AC 01 FA EF AF 9D 0A F0  1m.d.O.S........
0070: 9F 67 1E 76 D7 41 C9 62   2B 5B FB 42 E1 AF 55 F8  .g.v.A.b+[.B..U.

]
***
*** Diffie-Hellman ServerKeyExchange
DH Modulus:  { 233, 230, 66, 89, 157, 53, 95, 55, 201, 127, 253, 53, 103, 18, 11, 142, 37, 201, 205, 67, 233, 39, 179, 169, 103, 15, 190, 197, 216, 144, 20, 25, 34, 210, 195, 179, 173, 36, 128, 9, 55, 153, 134, 157, 30, 132, 106, 171, 73, 250, 176, 173, 38, 210, 206, 106, 34, 33, 157, 71, 11, 206, 125, 119, 125, 74, 33, 251, 233, 194, 112, 181, 127, 96, 112, 2, 243, 206, 248, 57, 54, 148, 207, 69, 238, 54, 136, 193, 26, 140, 86, 171, 18, 122, 61, 175 }
DH Base:  { 48, 71, 10, 213, 160, 5, 251, 20, 206, 45, 157, 205, 135, 227, 139, 199, 209, 177, 197, 250, 203, 174, 203, 233, 95, 25, 10, 167, 163, 29, 35, 196, 219, 188, 190, 6, 23, 69, 68, 64, 26, 91, 44, 2, 9, 101, 216, 194, 189, 33, 113, 211, 102, 132, 69, 119, 31, 116, 186, 8, 77, 32, 41, 216, 60, 28, 21, 133, 71, 243, 169, 241, 162, 113, 91, 226, 61, 81, 174, 77, 62, 90, 31, 106, 112, 100, 243, 22, 147, 58, 52, 109, 63, 82, 146, 82 }
Server DH Public Key:  { 73, 233, 14, 202, 89, 13, 188, 236, 57, 124, 97, 186, 86, 30, 193, 15, 117, 169, 125, 103, 204, 9, 145, 52, 184, 3, 58, 205, 66, 147, 131, 141, 40, 92, 208, 244, 197, 165, 243, 13, 18, 43, 68, 74, 135, 150, 21, 31, 181, 224, 98, 239, 200, 95, 130, 97, 202, 11, 152, 181, 123, 206, 248, 248, 146, 117, 167, 55, 30, 106, 64, 247, 45, 147, 134, 46, 36, 96, 50, 200, 140, 102, 166, 231, 229, 207, 210, 48, 211, 107, 181, 111, 6, 113, 57, 195 }
Signed with a DSA or RSA public key
New I/O worker #1, fatal error: 80: problem unwrapping net record
java.lang.RuntimeException: Delegated task threw Exception/Error
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
New I/O worker #1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
New I/O worker #1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 50                               ......P
New I/O worker #1, called closeOutbound()
New I/O worker #1, closeOutboundInternal()
```

**Client SSL debug**

```
testClient
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
client.start(): true
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1360012393 bytes = { 134, 128, 126, 2, 241, 35, 109, 215, 218, 46, 141, 218, 44, 43, 228, 29, 9, 155, 72, 100, 59, 29, 177, 236, 197, 205, 21, 138 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 149
0000: 01 00 00 91 03 01 51 10   24 69 86 80 7E 02 F1 23  ......Q.$i.....#
0010: 6D D7 DA 2E 8D DA 2C 2B   E4 1D 09 9B 48 64 3B 1D  m.....,+....Hd;.
0020: B1 EC C5 CD 15 8A 00 00   2A 00 33 C0 04 00 16 00  ........*.3.....
0030: 05 C0 03 C0 11 C0 02 C0   07 C0 13 C0 08 C0 0C 00  ................
0040: FF C0 0D C0 0E C0 09 00   2F C0 12 00 04 00 32 00  ......../.....2.
0050: 13 00 0A 01 00 00 3E 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......>...4.2...
0060: 01 00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................
0070: 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
0080: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00  ................
0090: 0B 00 02 01 00                                     .....
pool-5-thread-2, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
[Raw write]: length = 154
0000: 16 03 01 00 95 01 00 00   91 03 01 51 10 24 69 86  ...........Q.$i.
0010: 80 7E 02 F1 23 6D D7 DA   2E 8D DA 2C 2B E4 1D 09  ....#m.....,+...
0020: 9B 48 64 3B 1D B1 EC C5   CD 15 8A 00 00 2A 00 33  .Hd;.........*.3
0030: C0 04 00 16 00 05 C0 03   C0 11 C0 02 C0 07 C0 13  ................
0040: C0 08 C0 0C 00 FF C0 0D   C0 0E C0 09 00 2F C0 12  ............./..
0050: 00 04 00 32 00 13 00 0A   01 00 00 3E 00 0A 00 34  ...2.......>...4
0060: 00 32 00 17 00 01 00 03   00 13 00 15 00 06 00 07  .2..............
0070: 00 09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B   00 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E  ................
0080: 00 0F 00 10 00 11 00 02   00 12 00 04 00 05 00 14  ................
0090: 00 08 00 16 00 0B 00 02   01 00                    ..........
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 50                                              .P
New I/O worker #1, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
New I/O worker #1, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, internal_error
New I/O worker #1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
New I/O worker #1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
New I/O worker #1, called closeOutbound()
New I/O worker #1, closeOutboundInternal()
New I/O worker #1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
New I/O worker #1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
New I/O worker #1, called closeInbound()
New I/O worker #1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 01 00                               .......
main, called closeOutbound()
main, closeOutboundInternal()
New I/O worker #1, called closeOutbound()
New I/O worker #1, closeOutboundInternal()
```

**Security.java** (groups all security relevant stuff)

```
public class Security
{
    private static final String protocol    = "TLS";

    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    private static X509Certificate generateCertificate(String dn, KeyPair pair, String algorithm) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
    {
        PrivateKey privkey = pair.getPrivate();
        X509CertInfo info = new X509CertInfo();
        Date from = new Date();
        Date to = new Date(from.getTime() + 10l * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        CertificateValidity interval = new CertificateValidity(from, to);
        BigInteger sn = new BigInteger(64, new SecureRandom());
        X500Name owner = new X500Name(dn);

        info.set(X509CertInfo.VALIDITY, interval);
        info.set(X509CertInfo.SERIAL_NUMBER, new CertificateSerialNumber(sn));
        info.set(X509CertInfo.SUBJECT, new CertificateSubjectName(owner));
        info.set(X509CertInfo.ISSUER, new CertificateIssuerName(owner));
        info.set(X509CertInfo.KEY, new CertificateX509Key(pair.getPublic()));
        info.set(X509CertInfo.VERSION, new CertificateVersion(CertificateVersion.V3));
        AlgorithmId algo = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.md5WithRSAEncryption_oid);
        info.set(X509CertInfo.ALGORITHM_ID, new CertificateAlgorithmId(algo));

        // Sign the cert to identify the algorithm that's used.
        X509CertImpl cert = new X509CertImpl(info);
        cert.sign(privkey, algorithm);

        // Update the algorith, and resign.
        algo = (AlgorithmId) cert.get(X509CertImpl.SIG_ALG);
        info.set(CertificateAlgorithmId.NAME + "." + CertificateAlgorithmId.ALGORITHM, algo);
        cert = new X509CertImpl(info);
        cert.sign(privkey, algorithm);
        return cert;
    }

    protected static char[] getPassword()
    {
        return "test".toCharArray();
    }

    private static void pushKeyStoreToConfig(KeyStore ks, String configKey) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException,
        IOException
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ks.store(baos, Security.getPassword());
        Configuration.set(configKey, baos.toByteArray());
    }

    private KeyManager[]    keyManagers;
    private KeyStore        keyStore;
    private KeyStore        trustStore;
    private SSLContext      sslContext;

    private TrustManager[]  trustManagers;

    public Security()
    {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(Security.class).debug("constructing...");
    }

    public synchronized void addCertificate(String guid, Certificate certificate) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException,
        IOException
    {
        this.getTrustStore().setCertificateEntry(guid, certificate);
        Security.pushKeyStoreToConfig(this.getTrustStore(), Configuration.TRUST_STORE);
        Configuration.getInstance().save();
    }

    public SslHandler createSslHandler()
    {
        SSLEngine engine = this.getSslContext().createSSLEngine();
        engine.setUseClientMode(true);
        engine.setNeedClientAuth(true);
        return new SslHandler(engine);
    }

    public synchronized KeyManager[] getKeyManagers()
    {
        if (this.keyManagers == null)
        {
            KeyManager keyManager = new X509ExtendedKeyManager()
            {
                @Override
                public String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket)
                {
                    System.out.println("keymanager chooseClientAlias");
                    return Configuration.get(Configuration.GUID, String.class);
                }

                @Override
                public String chooseEngineClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, SSLEngine engine)
                {
                    System.out.println("keymanager chooseEngineClientAlias");
                    return Configuration.get(Configuration.GUID, String.class);
                }

                @Override
                public String chooseEngineServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, SSLEngine engine)
                {
                    System.out.println("keymanager chooseEngineServerAlias");
                    return Configuration.get(Configuration.GUID, String.class);
                }

                @Override
                public String chooseServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket)
                {
                    System.out.println("keymanager chooseServerAlias");
                    return Configuration.get(Configuration.GUID, String.class);
                }

                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias)
                {
                    System.out.println("keymanager getCertificateChain: " + alias);
                    try
                    {
                        Certificate[] certs = Security.this.getKeyStore().getCertificateChain(alias);
                        X509Certificate[] xcerts = new X509Certificate[certs.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < certs.length; i++)
                        {
                            xcerts[i] = (X509Certificate) certs[i];
                        }
                        return xcerts;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        LoggerFactory.getLogger(Security.class).error("Error while getting security chain", e);
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public String[] getClientAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers)
                {
                    System.out.println("keymanager getClientAliases");
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String alias)
                {
                    System.out.println("keymanager getPrivateKey: " + alias);
                    try
                    {
                        return (PrivateKey) Security.this.getKeyStore().getKey(alias, Security.getPassword());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        LoggerFactory.getLogger(Security.class).error("Error while getting private key", e);
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public String[] getServerAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers)
                {
                    System.out.println("keymanager getServerAliases");
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }
            };
            this.keyManagers = new KeyManager[] { keyManager };
        }
        return this.keyManagers;
    }

    public synchronized KeyStore getKeyStore() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
    {
        if (this.keyStore == null)
        {
            this.keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            try
            {
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(Configuration.get(Configuration.KEY_STORE, byte[].class));
                this.keyStore.load(bais, Security.getPassword());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LoggerFactory.getLogger(Security.class).warn("Could not load key store, creating new one", e);
                this.keyStore.load(null);
            }

            String guid = Configuration.get(Configuration.GUID, String.class);
            if (this.keyStore.getKey(guid, Security.getPassword()) == null)
            {
                this.resetKey(this.keyStore);
            }
            // TODO certificate expired? create new one!
        }
        return this.keyStore;
    }

    public synchronized SSLContext getSslContext()
    {
        if (this.sslContext == null)
        {
            SSLContext context = null;
            try
            {
                context = SSLContext.getInstance(Security.protocol);
                context.init(this.getKeyManagers(), this.getTrustManagers(), Controller.getInstance().getRandom());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Error("Failed to initialize the server-side SSLContext", e);
            }

            this.sslContext = context;
        }
        return this.sslContext;
    }

    private synchronized TrustManager[] getTrustManagers()
    {
        if (this.trustManagers == null)
        {
            TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager()
            {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException
                {
                    System.out.println("trustmanager checkClientTrusted");
                    this.checkTrusted(chain, authType);
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException
                {
                    System.out.println("trustmanager checkServerTrusted");
                    this.checkTrusted(chain, authType);
                }

                public void checkTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException
                {
                    Certificate cert = null;
                    try
                    {
                        cert = Security.this.getTrustStore().getCertificate(chain[0].getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
                        if (cert == null)
                        {
                            throw new CertificateException("Certificate is not trusted: " + chain[0]);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        throw new CertificateException("Error while validating certificate: " + chain[0], e);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
                {
                    return null;
                }
            };
            this.trustManagers = new TrustManager[] { trustManager };
        }
        return this.trustManagers;
    }

    protected synchronized KeyStore getTrustStore() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException
    {
        if (this.trustStore == null)
        {
            this.trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            try
            {
                this.trustStore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(Configuration.get(Configuration.TRUST_STORE, byte[].class)), Security.getPassword());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LoggerFactory.getLogger(Security.class).warn("Could not load trust store, creating new one", e);
                this.trustStore.load(null);
            }
        }
        return this.trustStore;
    }

    public synchronized void resetKey() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
    {
        this.resetKey(this.getKeyStore());
    }

    private synchronized void resetKey(KeyStore ks) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
    {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(Security.class).info("Creating a new key pair and certificate");
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(1024, Controller.getInstance().getRandom());
        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

        PrivateKey key = kp.getPrivate();
        String dn = "cn=" + Configuration.get(Configuration.GUID, String.class);
        X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[] { Security.generateCertificate(dn, kp, "SHA1withRSA") };

        ks.setKeyEntry(Configuration.get(Configuration.GUID, String.class), key, Security.getPassword(), chain);
        Security.pushKeyStoreToConfig(ks, Configuration.KEY_STORE);

        this.addCertificate(Configuration.get(Configuration.GUID, String.class), chain[0]);
    }
}
```

**Additional info**

setUseClientMode() is set from the outside in case of server engine.

Comment: This stops after receiving the server credentials.Have you put the server certificate in your trusstore?Show us your code

Comment: @Cratylus provided way more detail. I fear this is a bit overkill, though. =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This very less expressive error message is caused by a NullPointerException thrown in Java's handshaker which can be fixed by returning at least an empty list (you probably want more) in TrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers().

See [Oracle Bug ID 7148699: Handshaker throws NPE if TrustManager returns null from getAcceptedIssuers](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=ceec221faba405f38f9d3c0970ad?bug_id=7148699) for more details.